# How can I wrap fiddlercore with another proxy (in Qt)

Tags: qt, proxy, fiddlercore

I'm working with Qt webkit and fiddlercore. Generally I'm making a web-browser.
I exposed fiddlercore as a COM for Qt to access.
My program reads http response contents with fiddler.I know Qt can handle similar things with QNetworkAccessManager but this is not a choice for now.

Everything works fine but now I need to allow user to set an application-wise proxy.
In order for fiddlercore to run I need to set QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy as localhost:fiddler_port. How can I wrap this proxy with another overall proxy?

My approach is like:

My Program -> FiddlerCore(127.0.0.1:1234) -> OpenProxy(123.123.123.123:3129) -> internet

How can I do this with Qt?